# Может ли ресторан (заведение) быть вкусным?

Tags: прилагательные, словосочетания, лексическая-сочетаемость, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Скажите, можно ли сказать про ресторан, что он вкусный? С едой понятно, а вот насколько это слово применимо к заведениям, где подают вкусные блюда, не будет ли это ошибкой? Из литературных примеров пока нашёл только один с подобным словосочетанием.

*Еще при Lausanne Palace & Spa есть очень **вкусный ресторан** La Table du Palace, отмеченный звездой Michelin, а в этом ресторане ― отдельное развлечение: ужин на кухне шеф-повара.* [Яна Зубцова. Прекрасный маршрут (2002) // «Домовой», 04.04.2002]

Comment: Это общая тенденция современных русскоязычных авторов, когда выкидывается определяемое слово, очевидное для всех, связано с постмодерном головного мозга. Ресторан с вкусной кухней - вроде тавтология(или как там другое слово), хотя "вкусный ресторан" и "отмеченный звездой Мишлен", извините, "Michelin", уже тавтология, то есть сама по себе фраза уже криво составлена и показательна в плане языкового скилла пишущего: неумение пользоваться родным языком купируется иностранными конструкция, что, конечно, придает бездарной речи "изысканные" нотки. выбор из: плохо на двух языках или лучше,но на одном.

Comment: Разве что в непринужденной разговорной речи.

Comment: Режет слух, да и не слышу я подобного на постоянной основе. Любопытно посмотреть, есть ли прижившиеся примеры чего-то подобного.

Answer (score 1):

Почему нет? Это обычная метонимия.

Comment: Да, метонимия, но удачная или нет, другой вопрос.